# What do symbols in Xcode threads/queue view mean?

Tags: xcode

Every day during iOS development we are using Xcode' threads/queue view of the debug navigator to examine stack frames, switch between them and `po`, etc. vars and expressions. But I don't really understand all the icons (legend) in this window. I only know that blue-tinted icons show live stack frames and grey ones show recorded (historical) frames. But what each specific icon represents. I attached screenshots with different icons:

[image: debug view]

And another one:

[image: view]

As you can see each frame has it's own icon. I guess user image means user code(or not??), also there is an icon of a gear wheel, a mug(cup), a brick wall icon and a suitcase icon on the second screenshot.

Can someone point me to the doc where all these icons and their meanings are explained or if no such doc exists then explain what do they mean.

Comment: Good question. I've never questioned it but also I don't actually know. I guess it's frameworks? UIApplication is from CocoaTouch (mug of cocoa??). NSException is from Foundation. `main` is user written code. etc... But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]You can find answer in apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW19

Answer (score 0):

It's icons for different process. You can see more here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW19